# jQuery. Assign JSON as a result to a variable

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I use this helper function to receive JSON results for my requests:

```
function getData(url) {
    $.get(url,
         function(data) {
             response = data;
             return response;
         }, 'application/json');
}
```

I give it some string as a part of url from my web application, like '/api/getusers', so it looks like `getData('/api/getusers')`. Now I need that string result containing JSON data that I receive from the url to be assigned to my variable, so it would look like this: `var result = getData('/api/getusers')`. Then I will process this JSON data. The problem is with the returning the response variable. It's undefined. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's an asynchronous operation, meaning that `function(data) { ... }` runs *later* when the response from the server is available, long after you returned from `getData()`.  Instead, kick off whatever you need from that function, for example:

```
function getData(url, callback) {
    $.get(url, callback, 'application/json');
}
```

Then when you're calling it, pass in a function or reference to a function that uses the response, like this:

```
getData("myPage.php", function(data) {
  alert("The data returned was: " + data);
});
```

Answer (score 8):

try this

```
function getData(url) {
var data;
    $.ajax({
        async: false, //thats the trick
        url: 'http://www.example.com',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response){
           data = response;
        }
    });
    return data;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use $.ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.example.com',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
       alert(data.Id);
    }
});
```